# ¿Cómo puedo crear mis propios usuarios? C#

Tags: c#

estaba mirando si es posible crear un bloc de notas con 2 usuarios o 3 no sé, un ejemplo sería:

nombre;contraseña - sagc;1234

y ya dentro del software el Usuario ingresar esos datos y que al dar ingresar pueda ingresar con la contraseña verdadera, validando los datos del bloc de notas.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
/////////////////////////////////
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // USING PARA MOVER LA VENTANA SACADO DE INTERNET
/// /////////////////////////




namespace InicioSesion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        // CODIGO PARA PODER MOVER LA VENTANA
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
        private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]

        private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtuser_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ACA ES PARA QUE USUARIO CAMBIE DE COLOR
            if (txtuser.Text == "USUARIO")
            {
                txtuser.Text = "";
                txtuser.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
        }

        private void txtuser_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ACA SI ESTA VACIA LA CASILLA SE CONVERTIRÁ EN USURAIO OTRA VEZ
            if (txtuser.Text == "")
            {
                txtuser.Text = "USUARIO";
                // HACEMOS QUE EL COLOR DE FUENTE VUELVA A TENER EL COLOR GRIS OSCURO
                txtuser.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;

            }

        }

        private void txtpass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtpass_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtpass.Text == "CONTRASEÑA")
            {
                txtpass.Text = "";
                txtpass.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtpass_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtpass.Text=="")
            {
                txtpass.Text = "CONTRASEÑA";
                txtpass.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
                txtpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            }
        }


        private void btncerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
            // cerrar APP
        }

        private void btnminimizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            // MINIMIZAR APP
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // EVENTO MOUSE DOWN PARA MOVER LA APP
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // PARA QUE SE PUEDA MOVER EN EL PANEL
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En pocas palabras crear mis propios usuarios, Muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es manejar la autenticacion desde un bloc de notas ?

Comment: Si, yo poder crear mis usuarios.

Comment: Alguna razón por la que los quieras en un bloc de notas y no en una base de datos?

Comment: Porque unos compañeros dijeron que para empezar es mas fácil desde un bloc de notas. Me aconsejaron eso.

Comment: El manejo de las Bases de Datos es sencillo, te sugiero que en ves de aprender un metodo obsoleto, poco servible (por no decir inutil) e inseguro investiga sobre conexion a base de datos, ahi puede crear tus usuarios

Comment: Gracias ya lo voy hacer.

Comment: Como bien dice @srJJ, esto suele hacerse usando bases de datos. De todas maneras, si es a efectos educativos, puedes hacerlo con un archivo de texto perfectamente. Simplemente, mira que es un archivo [CSV](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas), [como leer y escribir archivos](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/304430/how-to-do-basic-file-i-o-in-visual-c) y el comando [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) para poder acceder a los datos